# Divergent or convergent but how ??

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I was to depict the convergence & divergence nature of the summation $\sum A_n$ where $A_n = (n^{1/n}-1)^k$ I was able to prove that when $k>1$ then $\sum A_n$ is converging and while $k<0$ it was diverging but when $1>k>0$ I saw the sequence $A_n$ to be increasing but I am unable to prove if the summation $\sum A_n$ is converging or diverging, so how do I prove it ?

Comment: You always have $A_n > 0$ for $k>0$. Thus, if the sequence is increasing, it can't be a null sequence. What does that tell you?

Comment: True if it's increasing then it must be divergent but then I only observed it whether by cauchy's ratio test or D'alembert's root test I am unable to prove if it's divergent or not

Answer (score 2):

Since $e^x\geq x+1$,

$$ n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1 = \exp\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)-1 \geq \frac{\log n}{n} $$
hence if $0<\alpha\leq 1$,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)^\alpha \geq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\log(n)^\alpha}{n^\alpha} $$
and the last series is diverging as $N\to +\infty$ by comparison with the generalized harmonic series.